# Restoring LaTeX native math look with new ACM templates

Tags: math-mode, acm

The new ACM templates produce a different look for the equations. (and my number 1 reason why I like LaTeX is that distinct and particularly awesome look of equations!)

As an example, for defining Fourier transform and discrete Fourier transform.  New ACM look:

[image]

Native LaTeX look:

[image]

The above two are produced from the *exact same* equation source code (the difference was the `\documentclass` that was used to produce each).

Is there a way to maintain the equations native look while leaving the rest of the layout and formatting as per the ACM template?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The new templates reflect the wishes of ACM. It's their journals.

Answer (score 1):

If I compile a modified sample from the `acmart` distribution

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e} % For algorithms
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{ALGORITHM}
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}
\IncMargin{-\parindent}


% Metadata Information
\acmJournal{TWEB}
\acmVolume{9}
\acmNumber{4}
\acmArticle{39}
\acmYear{2010}
\acmMonth{3}
\copyrightyear{2009}
%\acmArticleSeq{9}

% Copyright
%\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
%\setcopyright{rightsretained}
%\setcopyright{usgov}
%\setcopyright{usgovmixed}
%\setcopyright{cagov}
%\setcopyright{cagovmixed}

% DOI
\acmDOI{0000001.0000001}

% Paper history
\received{February 2007}
\received[revised]{March 2009}
\received[accepted]{June 2009}


% Document starts
\begin{document}
% Title portion. Note the short title for running heads
\title[A Multifrequency MAC for Wireless Sensor]{A Multifrequency MAC
  Specially Designed for Wireless Sensor  Network Applications}

\author{Gang Zhou}
\orcid{1234-5678-9012-3456}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{College of William and Mary}
  \streetaddress{104 Jamestown Rd}
  \city{Williamsburg}
  \state{VA}
  \postcode{23185}
  \country{USA}}
\email{gang_zhou@wm.edu}
\author{Valerie B\'eranger}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Inria Paris-Rocquencourt}
  \city{Rocquencourt}
  \country{France}
}
\email{beranger@inria.fr}
\author{Aparna Patel}
\affiliation{%
 \institution{Rajiv Gandhi University}
 \streetaddress{Rono-Hills}
 \city{Doimukh}
 \state{Arunachal Pradesh}
 \country{India}}
\email{aprna_patel@rguhs.ac.in}
\author{Huifen Chan}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Tsinghua University}
  \streetaddress{30 Shuangqing Rd}
  \city{Haidian Qu}
  \state{Beijing Shi}
  \country{China}
}
\email{chan0345@tsinghua.edu.cn}
\author{Ting Yan}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Eaton Innovation Center}
  \city{Prague}
  \country{Czech Republic}}
\email{yanting02@gmail.com}
\author{Tian He}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{University of Virginia}
  \department{School of Engineering}
  \city{Charlottesville}
  \state{VA}
  \postcode{22903}
  \country{USA}
}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{University of Minnesota}
  \country{USA}}
\email{tinghe@uva.edu}
\author{Chengdu Huang}
\author{John A. Stankovic}
\author{Tarek F. Abdelzaher}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{University of Virginia}
  \department{School of Engineering}
  \city{Charlottesville}
  \state{VA}
  \postcode{22903}
  \country{USA}
}


\begin{abstract}
Multifrequency media access control has been well understood in
general wireless ad hoc networks, while in wireless sensor networks,
researchers still focus on single frequency solutions. In wireless
sensor networks, each device is typically equipped with a single
radio transceiver and applications adopt much smaller packet sizes
compared to those in general wireless ad hoc networks. Hence, the
multifrequency MAC protocols proposed for general wireless ad hoc
networks are not suitable for wireless sensor network applications,
which we further demonstrate through our simulation experiments. In
this article, we propose MMSN, which takes advantage of
multifrequency availability while, at the same time, takes into
consideration the restrictions of wireless sensor networks. Through
extensive experiments, MMSN exhibits the prominent ability to utilize
parallel transmissions among neighboring nodes.
\end{abstract}


%
% The code below should be generated by the tool at
% http://dl.acm.org/ccs.cfm
% Please copy and paste the code instead of the example below.
%
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010562</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Embedded systems</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010575.10010755</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Redundancy</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010554</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Robotics</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10003033.10003083.10003095</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Networks~Network reliability</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
</ccs2012>
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Computer systems organization~Embedded systems}
\ccsdesc[300]{Computer systems organization~Redundancy}
\ccsdesc{Computer systems organization~Robotics}
\ccsdesc[100]{Networks~Network reliability}

%
% End generated code
%


\keywords{Wireless sensor networks, media access control,
multi-channel, radio interference, time synchronization}




\maketitle

% The default list of authors is too long for headers.
\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{G. Zhou et al.}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\{x\}&=\mathcal{X}(\omega)
  =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t)e^{-j\omega t}\,dt
\\
\mathcal{F}\{x\}&=\mathcal{X}(\omega)
  =\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} x(k)e^{-j\omega k}
\end{align}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

the display is typeset as

[image]

which is according to the wishes of ACM, according to the specifications laid out in the class written by Boris Veytsman, hired by the ACM as consultant. The class is *official* for publication in ACM journals and conferences.

If I save the following code in a file named `acmart-preload-hook.tex` in the working directory

```
\expandafter\def\csname ver@libertine.sty\endcsname{3000/12/31}
\expandafter\def\csname opt@libertine.sty\endcsname{tt=false,type1=true}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@newtxmath.sty\endcsname{3000/12/31}
\expandafter\def\csname opt@newtxmath.sty\endcsname{libertine}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@zi4.sty\endcsname{3000/12/31}
\expandafter\def\csname opt@zi4.sty\endcsname{varqu}
```

I get

[image]

I consider this abusing the class, though. Just use another one.

Comment: Just deleted my previous comment --- it wasn't working (option clash for libertine);  I just left the two middle lines (the ones with "newtxmath.sty" in them), and it works.  Can you explain why you had included the others?

Comment: @Cal-linux I think your TeX system is not up-to-date

Comment: I'm using the texlive packages from Ubuntu 16.04;  are those outdated?  I ended up installing the "metapackage" texlive-full; the error message changed; then, I uninstalled texlive-xxxxlibertinexxxx (whatever the exact name was), which forced uninstalling texlive-full and texlive-fonts-extras;  the error message changed again....  in the end, keeping only the two middle lines worked  (???)

Comment: @Cal-linux The TeX Live provided by Ubuntu is always outdated.